# If I transform into a vampire lord and kill someone and then transform back to human form, will I be recognized?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I want to know, in Skyrim XBOX One, if I hid and became a vampire lord, then went into Riften, killed someone, left and hid, then became a human, as long as no one saw me transform, will I be recognized by guards? Or could I wear a guards helmet that concealed my eyes, would that help? And will I be shunned by NPCs because my eyes glow? Thanks

Comment: I didn't think I'd ever see a great question about Skyrim in 2017, but here it is.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[According to this site,](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:264026?useskin=oasis) if you transform into the Vampire Lord, all bounties you incur as a Vampire Lord will disappear as long as no one sees you enter and exit Vampire Lord mode. This is probably because they just see the big, demonic, vampire, and not you, the scrawny red-eyed adventurer

Comment: Thank you! Now I can kill for the Dark Brotherhood without fear!

Comment: This works the same for werewolves, too.